# Proof involving vectors spaces and endomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure how to go about this problem.

Let $U$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field. There exists some $T \in End(U)$ such that $T^2 = T$. Show that $U = U_1 + U_0$ with $T(u_1) = u_1$ for all $u_1 \in U_1$ and $T(u_0) = 0$ for all $u_0 \in U_0$.

Could someone point me along the right track and help me with this proof? Thanks, Lauren.

Comment: Are you familiar with the kernal and image of a linear transformation? Do you know their definitions and are you happy with identifying them as subspaces of their respective domain and codomain?

Comment: Yes, I am happy with those concepts.

Comment: Can you make a guess then at what subspaces of $U$, the sets $U_0$ and $U_1$ might be?

Comment: Well having said that, and given the fact that the map is an endomorphism, I'm going to say that $U_0$ is the kernel and $U_1$ is the image?

Comment: That seems like a reasonable guess! Because $U$ is finite dimensional, can you find a good basis in which to help with this problem? (Hint, $T^{-1}(0)$ is a subspace, right?)

Comment: Would $T^{-1} (0)$ also be the kernel ($U_0$)? I'm not sure... I'll take a guess at a basis of eigenvectors of $T$.

Answer (score 1):

we don't need too much involvement of what happens to individual vectors, since the essence of the question concerns the structure of an endomorphism of $V$ in terms of its subspaces. we are asked to show a certain consequence of the constraint that the endomorphism is a projection operator, or what amounts rto the same thing, that all its eigenvalues are zero or unity. effectively we can decompose the space $U$ into a direct sum on the basis of these eigenvalues.

so we might try something along these lines:

the equation $T(I-T)=(I-T)T=0$ implies
$$
\begin{align}
Im(I-T) & \subset Ker(T) \\
Im(T) &\subset Ker(I-T)
\end{align}
$$
if $Tv$=0 then $(I-T)v \ne 0$ and vice versa, so
$$
Ker(T) \cap Ker(I-T)=0
$$
which forces
$$
Im(T) \cap Im(I-T)=0 \tag{1}
$$
but also
$$
U = Im(I) = Im( T + I - T) \subset Im(T) + Im(I-T) \tag{2}
$$
from (1) and (2)
$$
U = Im(T) \oplus Im(I-T)
$$